# Selecting rows from 2 columns based on a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list which contains a list of indices. Now, I want to select two columns from a dataframe according to the indices.

I am trying:

```
indices = full_train_df.query("primary == primary").index
X = train_df[["A","B"]][:clean_df_indices].values
y = train_df["year"][:clean_df_indices].values
```

However, it says that none of them are in the index. What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: could you show an example of yuor dataframe and your expeted output?

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc` like this:

```py
indices = full_train_df.query("primary == primary").index 
X = train_df.loc[:clean_df_indices, ["A","B"]].values 
y = train_df.loc[:clean_df_indices, "year"].values
```